# Share Facebook App ID across multiple apps

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I have a Facebook app ID which I'm using on 6 iOS apps for sharing posts on the user's timeline using Single Sign-on (SSO).

I have setup the custom URL Scheme suffix described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#multipleapps) and it's working fine right now.

My question is regarding the "iPhone App Store ID" and "iPad App Store ID" fields listed on the Facebook app settings. From what I understood [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#linktoapp), these IDs would only be used if the user started an action on the Facebook app that would required my app to be installed. It would then be redirected to the AppStore ID listed on those fields.

My question is: is this really what these fields are for? I'd rather not forward the user anywhere (leave this blank?) but it's not allowed. Maybe I should just fill it with my app's free version AppStore IDs?

Comment: Try asking at http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers as they tend to lean towards questions of the administration nature.  We're programmers here.  If you need help with code you're writing we'd be glad to help.

Comment: @DMCS I think this is a legit programming question if you are a Facebook and iOS developer - see my answer below.

Comment: @Nick, Actually, just take a gander at the dbdevelopers page.  It says basically what I just paraphrased.  See for yourself at facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers

Comment: I didn't say fbdevelopers wasn't a good place to get an answer for this question - I objected to the suggestion that stack overflow wasn't a good place, or that this question was off topic. There's no rule that says not to ask questions on stack overflow that might be answered somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fill in those values, users who have your Facebook app installed will see the icon for your iOS app appear in the applications sidebar within the native iOS Facebook app on their iPhone.

Tapping that icon will then either launch your native app (if it's installed) or take them to the App Store page for that app so they can install it.

If you are using your Facebook app with multiple iOS apps, then you'll either have to pick one of your native apps to be *the* native app that represents your Facebook app, or just leave the fields blank.

There is no way to associate multiple native apps with a single Facebook app AFAIK.

Comment: Since things changed since this answer, currently is possible to have the same FB app shared between different iOS apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting#sharedappid